# Cordova Ionic Java Version Error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to to create an android apk File in ionic cordova, my app seem to run and work fine but when i type `ionic cordova build android` in the cmd i am getting the following error JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1
(node:11108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater, i have created the path and my java version is 9.0.1 but i can figure out why is not working properly can anyone please provide me some help

Thanks in Regards

Comment: Install JDK 8.x and try

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with java jdk 9+ version. You should uninstall java jre, jdk and install lower version from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Also don't forget to change variables JAVA_HOME and Path